# Problem building array of PHP echo statements to return through Ajax call (not working)

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, post

After reading through many Stack Overflow posts, I thought I was understanding how to return echo statements through an Ajax call. I'm attempting to build an array of echo statements that result from the various steps of the POST (php). But it's turning out more complicated than I thought and I would appreciate some input. Here is my Ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/phpscripts/ss_save_ws_1.1.php',
            dataType: "json",
            data: {session_userid, session_exist, grid_export},
            success:(function(response, status, xhr){
                console.log("Response:", response);
                console.log("Status:", status);
                console.log("XHR:", xhr);
            })
```

In my php file, I declare the array:

```
$response_arr = array();
```

... and then throughout the various stages I include the following:

```
if (mysqli_query($dbc, $sql_query)) {
    $response_arr["sql_delete"] = "Successful";
} else {
    $response_arr["sql_delete"] = "Failed";
}
```

... and

```
if (mysqli_query($dbc, $sql_update)) {
    $response_arr["sql_update"] = "Successful";
} else {
    $response_arr["sql_update"] = "Failed";
}
```

.. and then at the end of the file I include:

```
echo json_encode($response_arr);
```

The problem is every stage runs successfully and the mySQL database is updated exactly as I want but on the Ajax side I get no information. The Success "response" is totally empty. Am I going about this the wrong way? Is my method in building the array incorrect? Because I don't have 'console.log' to rely on here (PHP server-side), I really don't know for sure if any of my code is actually working. Clearly, I'm new at this but I'm willing to learn. Thank you for any help you can provide.

Network Output:

```
// global variables to keep track of the request
// and the function to call when done
var ajaxreq=false, ajaxCallback;

// ajaxRequest: Sets up a request
function ajaxRequest(url, params) { 
   try {
      //make a new request object
      ajaxreq= new XMLHttpRequest();
   } catch (error) {
      return false;
   }
   ajaxreq.open("POST", url);
   ajaxreq.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
   ajaxreq.onreadystatechange = ajaxResponse;
   ajaxreq.send(params);
}

// ajaxResponse: Waits for response and calls a function
function ajaxResponse() {
   if (ajaxreq.readyState !=4) return;
   if (ajaxreq.status==200) {
      // if the request succeeded...
      if (ajaxCallback) ajaxCallback();
   } else alert("Request failed: " + ajaxreq.statusText);
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Inspect the request in your browser dev tools, network panel - what does it show there, what the response was?

Comment: Open your browser's developer toolbar and click the network tab. There, click on the AJAX request and you will have the option to see the response for it. When you click on the response, you'll see any output the script makes, including any debugging (like `var_dump`).

Comment: Also, try and remove `dataType: "json"` from your AJAX request, for the time being. If your PHP script generated any output besides the JSON, then the whole response can not be decoded as JSON, so you might also get an “empty” response in your success handler due to that.

Comment: You show us unconnected fragmants. **Could this be a Scope issue?** Show us what really happens in your code

Comment: What do you mean by "empty"? What hav you tried to debug the problem? Are you sure this is in any way related to AJAX itself?

Comment: Hello. I have never looked at "Network" before so I look forward to exploring. In the meantime, I will add the outcome to my question.

Comment: @Nico Haase when I review the output from "console.log("response", response);" it is totally empty. Nothing in it. That is what I mean by "empty."

Comment: @RiggsFolly I will look at that although I have tried many iterations. But if "Scope" is a possibility, I will take another look. Thank you.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you for the suggestion. I will give that a try after I learn what 'Network' shows me. This may help in my debugging. Much appreciated!

Comment: @RiggsFolly YOU were right. Scope issue was also one of the culprits. Thanks for alerting me to that possibility. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello and thank you for all of the helpful input.

Based on a number of suggestions — including the use of "Network" (which I have not used before but will from this point forward) — I was able to see that my method to build the associative array was causing the problem. These two versions work perfectly:

```
$response_arr += ['sql_delete' => 'Success'];
$response_arr['sql_update'] = 'Success';
```

Thank you Stack Overflow Experts! I appreciate all of your support.